# C# Setting object DateTime property values through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-4.0, system.reflection

I want to set all DateTime properties of my object to a default date. However, if I try do set the values through reflection I get the exception: "Object does not match target type."

```
private void SetDefaultValues()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000", new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
        {                                      
            p.SetValue(dt, typeof(DateTime), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing / thinking something fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: What's the reason for setting these through reflection instead of directly? If you have a ton that need to be set, you could consider putting them in a List or a Dictionary.

Comment: Any reason to avoid standard properties with a getter returning a class var with your default date?

Comment: I have tried to do similar functionality in a multi-level inheritance nightmare implementing a custom deserialization method based on reflection. The performance is terrible!  You're better off using partial classes and writing a code generator.  (my $0.02).

Comment: I need to set all DateTime properties to a "standard" date because the object they belong to is an EF Code First object which means: I can't save DateTime properties to the SQL CE DB if they have a DateTime.MinValue (hope you understand what I mean...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters need adjusting; the first is the *target* - which I assume is `this` here; the *second* is the value (`dt`). The last relates to "indexers" - which probably doesn't apply here.

```
p.SetValue(this, dt, null);
```